# There is no option to modify laptop brightness on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, brightness

There is option to modify system sound but no option to modify system **brightness** on Ubuntu.

**$ lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

**How to modify laptop brightness ?**

Answer (score 1):

Check the max brightness:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/*/max_brightness
```

sample output:

```
96000
```

Set brightness:

```
echo 20000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
```

[see ACPI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#ACPI)

Or use `xbacklight` installed through : `sdo apt install xbacklight`

```
xbacklight -inc 10
xbacklight -dec 10
```

[see xblacklight](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#xbacklight)

Comment: after installing **xbacklight** I executed the above commands but brightness was not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [using the slider on the System Menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-brightness.html.en)?

Also, many laptops have hardware/BIOS settings to change brightness by keypress, which might still work in Virtualbox.

Comment: @Pippik there is no slider for brightness on the System menu.

Comment: Perhaps that component of Ubuntu was not virtualized.

Comment: Is it possible to virtualize that component?